# Replace a field in a javascript Object? with splice and push, indexOf to splice is returning -1 value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, indexing

I have an array that at any point may contain any combination of the following values:

```
var positions = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth'];
```

The goal is to rebuild a Javascript Object that, by default, is set to:

```
currentPositioning = { 'positioning': [
                                      { 'first': false },
                                      { 'second': false },
                                      { 'third': false },
                                      { 'fourth': false } 
                                    ]
                                };
```

The positions array is looped through to rebuild the currentPositioning Object:

```
positions.forEach(setPositions);
function setPositions(element, index, array) {
    if (element == 'first') {
        // define objSplice object
        var objSplice = {};
        // set object of 'array.element' to false .. {'element': false}
        objSplice[element] = false;
        console.log('objSplice = ' + JSON.stringify(objSplice));
        // find index that matches {'element': false}
        var index = currentPositioning["positioning"].indexOf( objSplice );
        console.log('index = ' + index);
        if (index > -1) {
                // remove index that matches {'element': false}
            currentPositioning["positioning"].splice(index, 1);
        }
        // define obj object
        var obj = {};
        // set obj object of 'array.element' to true .. {'element': true}
        obj[element] = true;
        // add {'element': true} to array
        currentPositioning["positioning"].push( obj );
    }
    if (element == 'second') {
        ...
```

Basically, if one of the positions is in the positions array, then that position in the  currentPositioning Object **should** be set to `true` ..otherwise it should remain `false`

The idea is that..when..

```
var positions = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
```

..then..

```
currentPositioning = { 'positioning': [
                                      { 'first': true },
                                      { 'second': true },
                                      { 'third': true },
                                      { 'fourth': false } 
                                    ]
                                };
```

For some reason though, right now the `index = -1` .. every time .. so the result keeps turning to something like this!? :

```
currentPositioning = { 'positioning': [
                                      { 'first': false },
                                      { 'second': false },
                                      { 'third': false },
                                      { 'fourth': false },
                                      { 'first': true },
                                      { 'second': true },
                                      { 'third': true },
                                    ]
                                };
```

Comment: any better practice is more than welcome, and definitely appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) to do this (I've added some temp variables to improve readibility):

```
var positions = ['first', 'second', 'third'];

var updatedPositions = _.map(['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth'], function(p) {
  var json={};
  json[p] = _.contains(positions,p);
  return json;
});

var currentPositioning = { 'positioning': [
  updatedPositions
]
};
```

Comment: Thanks.. First exposure to underscore though.. Could you walk through the answer a bit? I npm installed underscore, and now require('underscore'), but this doesn't seem to be running.. where does this fit in to the question codeset?

Comment: It would replace `positions.forEach(setPositions);` and the `setPositions` function. To check that underscore is correctly installed and required `typeof _ === 'undefined'` should equal false